# Importing jetty libraries

Tags: java, intellij-idea, gradle, build, jetty

I wanna use jetty in my project. I'm building it with Gradle. IntelliJ tells "Cannot resolve symbol jetty" in the following row `import org.eclipse.jetty.server.Server;` How to fix this? Here are my project directories and gradle dependencies:[image][image]

Answer (score 0):

Use maven central to grab jetty dependencies. Put the following in your build.gradle:

```
repositories {
  mavenCentral()
}

dependencies {
  compile 'org.eclipse.jetty:jetty-webapp:9.4.0.v20161208'
}
```

Comment: This Jetty version forces the min API level to be 26, `Error:com.android.dx.cf.code.SimException: invalid opcode ba (invokedynamic requires --min-sdk-version >= 26)`